# how to execute a script Rhel 7 at booting time?

Tags: linux-networking, systemd, upstart, rhel7

I am trying to execute a shell script on RHEL7.1 when the machine starts. As in ubuntu, Upstart scripts (in /etc/init/) are used to execute any scripts or to start any services at boot time, is there anything equivalent in RHEL 7.1 to upstart?

Comment: Red Hat got rid of upstart (because it was crap). It uses systemd now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to execute `example.service` at booting time, you'd do:

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/example.service
```

with this content:

```
 [Unit] 
 Description=Example 
 After=network.target 

 [Service] 
 Type=simple 
 WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/example
 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/example --pid /var/run/example.pid --core unlimited -c /etc/example/example.ini 
 Restart=always 
 User=root
 Group=root 
 LimitNOFILE=10240 
 LimitFSIZE=infinity

 [Install] 
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, just start and enable it:

```
systemctl start example.service
systemctl enable example.service
```

Comment: In my case I've got a shell script to execute, so I need to provide the apth to that shell script in ExecStart=/home/scripts/temp.sh, right? and while rebooting the shell script will get executed?

Comment: Yeah, that's right

Comment: Depending on what the script does, you may want `Type=oneshot` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Add the scrpit in /etc/rc.d/rc.local file, The script will be automatically executed during boot.

Comment: That works in RHEL6, not 7